# Why is the duration of recorded audio negative? (iOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I want to record an M4A format audio file with my app and play it afterwards.
My app fails to do so the first time I try to record, but mysteriously works flawlessly in the 2nd, 3rd, and further attempts.
Printing the value of audioPlayer.duration reveals that the first audio recording always has a negative value! Why?? Every other audio recording have positive duration values in seconds, as expected.
I ALWAYS USE THE SAME FILENAME FOR ALL RECORDINGS, OVERWRITING THE PREVIOUS RECORD. What am I doing wrong?

```
    func initializeRecorder(){
    let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(32000.0)),
                                  AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)), 
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Low.rawValue)) ]

            var error : NSError?
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {
                try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.directoryURL(),
                                                    settings: recordSettings)
                audioRecorder.delegate = self
                audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
                audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
                print("M4a Recorder Initialized - OK...")
            } catch {
                print("Init Error")
            }
        }

    func recordSpeechM4A(){
        if !audioRecorder.recording {
            isCapioRecording=true
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
                print("**** RECORDING ****")
                audioRecorder.record()
            } catch {
                print("RECORDING ERROR")
            }
        }
    }

func stopRecording(){
        audioRecorder.stop()
}
func playRecordedAudio(){
        if (!audioRecorder.recording){
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioRecorder.url)
                audioPlayer.play()

                print("PLAYING AUDIO...: "+audioRecorder.url.description)
                print("Audio duration: "+audioPlayer.duration.description)
                //DURATION OF THE 1st RECORDING IS ALWAYS NEGATIVE!!!
            } catch {
                print("AUDIO PLAYBACK ERROR")
            }
        }
    }

// I ALWAYS USE THE SAME FILENAME!
func directoryURL() -> NSURL {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        filepath = urls[0]
        let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL
        print("STORAGE DIR: "+documentDirectory.description)
        let soundURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.m4a") //.m4a
        print("SAVING FILE: "+soundURL.description)
        return soundURL
    }
```

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: Hi @BhargavB.Bajani I have done tons of coding since this question, so sorry if my memory fails here. I remember iOS is VERY delicate with the audio format it can handle. One small variation and everything falls apart. Digging into my project´s code I noticed only one difference with my code on this question: Change the sample rate from 32000, and use *16000*. Let me know if it works. Good luck.

Comment: hi @josh... actually i'm not applying any settings. and also i check by applying setting but not work properly. same issue

Comment: @BhargavB.Bajani you should apply settings, otherwise, default values will be used and probably fail.

Comment: also checked by applying value but  problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had fixed it by the below snippet:

```
audioRecorder.record()
audioRecorder.record()
```

by calling this function twice, although this might not be the ideal solution.
Somehow it fixed it.